# How can I stop dress shirts from billowing in the back/on the sides?

Tags: clothing

I've noticed that around a couple hours after I tuck in my dress shirt to my suit, the sides and back will begin to puff out. And even when I tuck in the sides, the back will have a lot of excess shirt.

For example:

[image]

Notice that even if the shirt was completely tucked into the sides, the back would still be very puffy as a result of the excess shirt material. I am around average height and weight (5' 11", 160lbs) and I have already tried buying slim shirts (which mitigated, but did not solve, the problem).

Comment: Don't move after you put it on. The shirt will never billow!

Comment: @liebs19: I think the questions being asked are different. In that question, the asker is unable to keep his shirt in his pants. Here, I am concerned with how to keep a certain aspect tight. While the answers might have some overlap, they are serving different end goals.

Comment: @JSW189 I don't see how they are different enough to attract different answers. It seems like this question is just about what to do when your shirt comes untucked but not all the way untucked. If others agree they are different enough I will retract my close vote.

Comment: This is not a duplicate question at all. My answer is - invest in a Ledbury shirt (online sales only as far as I know). No I don't work for them, but I've bought 4.

Comment: This is an entirely different question. The shirt is tucked in but too big. You need to buy "fitted" shirts, which are more body-shaped. The shirt in the picture is a size too big as well.

Comment: If you have access to a sewing machine, sew darts in the shirt, and take in the side-seams a bit. If not, go to a garment alteration service. Cheaper than you expect.